# how to check QT_VERSION to include different header?

Tags: c++, qt

Qt4 and Qt5 have different organization of header files. So I need to check the qt version to include different things, for example:

```
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
    #include <QtMultimedia>
#endif
```

however, this seems does not work. The QT_VERSION has not been defined. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: It's declared in the header file `<QtGlobal>` (or `"qglobal.h"`). Check if you included them in the project.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

As @Tay2510 commented, `QT_VERSION` is declared inside of `<QtGlobal>`. As a result, you must type `#include <QtGlobal>` or another header that includes `<QtGlobal>`, before the version dependent [preprocessor directives](http://www.codingunit.com/cplusplus-tutorial-preprocessor-directives).

`<QObject>` and `<QCoreApplication>` may also be used to access `QT_VERSION`.

Here is an example of the code:

```
#include <QtGlobal>
#if QT_VERSION >= 0x050000
    #include <QApplication>
#else
    #include <QtGui/QApplication>
#endif
```

Remember that the qmake project should also handle version variations.
[Here are changes that should be done when using the QT multimedia library](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/changes.html):

The .pro file should look something like:

```
QT += core gui

greaterThan(4, QT_MAJOR_VERSION): QT += widgets multimedia
lessThan(5, QT_MAJOR_VERSION): CONFIG += mobility
lessThan(5, QT_MAJOR_VERSION): MOBILITY += multimedia
```

Answer (score 89):

As soon as you include `<QtGlobal>` you can check that with macros:

```
#if QT_VERSION < QT_VERSION_CHECK(5, 0, 0)
```

It's the same as @Javier suggested, just a different, more readable to me, syntax

Comment: While this solution is indeed more readable (and thus got my upvote), it should be noted that `moc` is unable to understand it. For example I wanted to use QOpenGLWidget where available (Qt >= 5.4) and otherwise fall back to QGLWidget. But that only works if I use `QT_VERSION >= 0x050400` and not if I use the solution of this answer.

Comment: @josch I never had troubles with that, though they say qmake from QT4 doesn't expand macros, so it obviously doesn't work for QT4. Do you have such an issue with QT5?

Comment: Correct, I have it with Qt 5.3.1